# How to select only certain updates on Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server, updates

I am trying to find out how I can select what updates I want to install vs. installing everything available on Ubuntu Server 16.04. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,
Donny T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1- List updates

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade
# -s: simulate, dont download and dont install
```

-2- Update manually the packages you want

```
apt-get install <packagename>
# will update installed package
```

Of course, dependencies will be updated or outdated...
You may run `apt-get install -f` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Run `aptitude` and press 'u' to get the list of updates.

Press 'U' to mark them all for updating.

Press 'g' to see the list.

Go down the list and press '=' on each package you do not wish to upgrade.

Press 'g' to complete the upgrade.